# Android gradle duplicate build.gradle reference

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project which is composed of two modules, app and TapsellDeveloperSDK. the TapsellDeveloperSDK module is added just fine and works perfectly.

the only problem is that in the left hand window in Android Studio, there are three references to TapsellDeveloperSDK/build.gradle file while there is only one file in the filesystem, and everything works FINE!

Does anyone know why is that? is it a bug?

Comment: are you in the *Android* project view and those 3 files show up at the `Gradle Scripts` node?

Comment: Yes, It is really just one file. It just shows it three times.